# php trim function does not work

Tags: php

why this always show string 8 although used trim() function? It should remove whitespaces from both side?

```
            $text = " Raveen ";             
            echo "Before trim: ".strlen($text); //prints 8
            trim($text);
            echo "<br>After trim: ".strlen($text); //now prints 6
```

Comment: Yes trim remove whitespace from both side.

Comment: You probably want to assign the **return value** of trim to the variable again

Comment: `trim()` return the modified string, it does not modify the variables. So you have to store modified value/string to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't echoing the new variable, you're taking a variable, giving it a new form but not assigning it to anything.

```
 $text = " Raveen ";             
 echo "Before trim: ".strlen($text); //prints 8
 echo "<br>After trim: ".strlen(trim($text)); //now prints 6
```

Thats works how you want it to work. Or something like:

```
 $text = " Raveen ";             
 echo "Before trim: ".strlen($text); //prints 8
 $text = trim($text);
 echo "<br>After trim: ".strlen($text); //now prints 6
```

I'm convinced you know how the Trim function actually works, so links to that aren't useful. Despite this, It wouldn't hurt looking through [some simple examples to get you on the right track](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp)

Answer (score 3):

PHP trim() function returns the trimmed string, documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), so the code would be like:

```
$text = " Raveen ";             
echo "Before trim: ".strlen($text); //prints 8
$trimed_text = trim($text);
echo "<br>After trim: ".strlen($trimed_text); //now prints 6
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP trim() function removes white space but it doesn't change the origional string it returns result as a string.
Your code should be like this:

```
        $text = " Raveen ";             
        echo "Before trim: ".strlen($text); //prints 8
        echo "<br>After trim: ".strlen(trim($text)); //now prints 6
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:
 `trim($text);` to `$text = trim($text);`

```
$text = " Raveen ";             
echo "Before trim: ".strlen($text); //prints 8
$text = trim($text);
echo "<br>After trim: ".strlen($text); //now prints
```

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
trim($text);
```

to

```
$text = trim($text);
```